# Overloading * operator for string in C++

Tags: c++, string, memory, operator-overloading

I need to multiplicate a string X-times using this (*) operator. For example:

```
 String a = "First";
 String b = a*2; // then b = "FirstFirst"
```

But it crashes. What is the most strangest thing, that it crashes from time to time. Few times it works and then crashes.

So here is my string-class:

```
    class String {
      int len;
      char *str;
    public:
      String () {
      len = 0;
      str = NULL;
      }
      String(const char *);
      String(const String &);
      ~String() {
      delete [] str;
      }
      String operator++(int notused);
      String & operator =(const String &); 
      friend int operator == (const String &, const String &); 
      friend ostream & operator <<(ostream &, const String &);
      friend istream & operator >>(istream &, const String &);
      friend String operator*(const String & s1, int x);
      friend String operator*(int x, const String & s1);
    };
```

And here is overloading of * operator and some constructors:

```
      String::String(const char * ptr)
      {
       str = new char [(len = strlen(ptr)) + 1];
       strcpy(str, ptr);
      }

      String::String(const String & s)
      {
       str = NULL;
       if(len = s.len){
       str = new char [len + 1];
       strcpy(str, s.str);
       }
      }
      String operator*(const String & s1, int x)
      {
         String result = s1;
         result.str = new char[(s1.len)*x];
         strcpy (result.str, s1.str);
         result.len = x*s1.len;;
         for (int i = 0; i < (x-1); i++)
         {
           strcat (result.str, s1.str);
         }
         return result;
      }
```

First of all I checked the length of a strings. But they're ok (I think), so what's the problem?

So, I have allocated new memory with the following lines:

```
    String result = s1;
    result.str = new char[(s1.len)*x];
```

And it works pefectly for numbers from 0 to 7. And at 8 it crashes. It's all about size. If I multiply double-X times:

```
result.str = new char[(s1.len)*x*x];
```

Then I can cross 8-barrier. And sometimes I see bad_alloc error.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: "But they're ok (I think)" - why the "I think"? Your debugger will tell you all about it so you don't have to doubt your thinking.

Comment: Currently I'm reading how to use them, But I thought, that may be somebody had similiar problem, so i posted the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you are not allocating new memory in `operator*`

`strcpy` and `strcat` assume that char array is large enough to contain the resulting string.

You should allocate enough memory so it is done in constructors.

Comment: The problem starts with `strcpy`.

Comment: Yeah. Allocation of new memory. It helped. Thank you. I just needed to understand how eactly implement allocation to my code.